# AD: DHCP and DNS IP source

Tags: active-directory

In an Active Directory set up, which is the server that issues the DHCP and DNS IP when clients do an auto detect connection settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whichever server is setup as the DHCP server. Installing AD does not install DHCP for you. You must install DHCP on a server or enable it on your router or firewall. The DHCP service is what gives out IP addresses and DNS server addresses.